# How can I get the data inside my notifications from within my Controller?

Tags: laravel

I'm trying to get the numbers of records from my notifications, where the candidate_user_id column from inside the data attribute is the same as the UserId (Authenticated User).

After I dd, I was able to get the data from all of the records in the table by using the pluck method (Line 1). I then tried to use the Where clause to get the items that I need
but this just didn't work, it was still returning all of the records in the table.

DashboardController.php:

```
public function index()
    {
        $notifications = Notification::all()->pluck('data');

        $notifications->where('candidate_user_id', Auth::user()->id);

        dd($notifications);

    }
```

Here is a partial screenshot of the data that is being plucked.
[image]

How can I get the data from this, in a way like this `->where('candidate_user_id', Auth::user()->id);`?

Comment: So when a Candidate sends his resume to an employer, only the Employer receives a notification. After seeing your answer, I think it would make sense for the Candidate to receive a notification as well. This way I can access his notification more easily like you mentioned above. Thank you!

Comment: Hey sorry, When a Candidate responds to an Interview Request, only the Employer gets notified. In the data, I store the candidate_user_id and so I still need to know how to access this via my original question above. I don't feel like adding more notifications for the candidate, simply from responding to an Interview Request, date and time that is convenient to setup and interview. So my issue is not solved.

Comment: you can get `candidate_user` and still do `->notifications` to get all the notifications for specific `user`.

Comment: my answer is just an example I used `auth` user. you can use any user from laravel `Model`.

Comment: I also updated my answer for u, if you really want to do it in your question way.

Comment: how is this `data` field defined in the schema?

Comment: Sorry Andy, I tried your updated answered code and when I die/dump it just returns an empty array [].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `data` was a JSON field on the table you could try to use a `where` condition to search the JSON using the `->` operator:

```
Notification::where('data->candidate_user_id', Auth::id())->pluck('data');
```

Assuming you only want this `data` field and not the rest of the fields, you can call `pluck` on the builder directly. There isn't much reason to hydrate Model instances with all the fields to then just pluck a single field from them if it is just a table field, so you can ask the database for just the field you want.

Comment: #lagbox - This code worked on Local. But on my production server I get this error:
[previous exception] [object] (PDOException(code: 42000): SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1305 FUNCTION .json_unquote does not exist

#8/home/ymq6es2sf6km/highrjobs/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.php(689): Illuminate\\Database\\Query\\Builder->pluck('data', NULL)

#9 /home/ymq6es2sf6km/highrjobs/app/Http/Controllers/DashboardController.php(19): Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\Builder->pluck('data')
Any how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

The data in the `data` field is a json string, so you can tell Laravel to automatically cast it as an array using the `$casts` property on each of the models that is notifiable.

For instance, if you have a `User` model which uses the trait (ie has `use Notifiable`), add this:

```
protected $casts = [
    'data' => 'array',
];
```

Comment: I added this to my User model, but the data looks the exact same like a json string when I die/dump it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access all notifications for the `auth` user.

```php
$user = auth()->user();
dd($user->notifications->pluck('data'));
```

If you really want to do in your question way, here is how.

```php
$notifications = Notification::all()->pluck('data');

$notifications = $notifications->where('candidate_user_id', Auth::user()->id)
                 ->all();
```

This assumes you that you did not modify the default laravel notifications relationship and database migration setup. If you have modified some of the default ones, you need to provide how you modify it.

Comment: Pretty sure I did not modify anything. Did not know you can use ->all(). I’ll look into it tomorrow.

Comment: @RyanSacks the thing is that `where` does not modify the collection, so you need to assign to the `$notifications` variable.